# What user runs the commands defined in /etc/rc.local?

Tags: linux, sudo, startup, su

Are the commands in `/etc/rc.local` ran by `su` by default?
Do I need to specific `sudo` before each command or will they be ran by `su` regardless?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`su` is not a **user** it's *program* to run subsequent commands/programs under an alternate identity of another user than the one executing the command. It is very similar to `sudo` in that regard.

Unless another user is specified both commands will default to running the command under the alternate identity of the **`root`** user, the superuser/administrator.

The main difference between `su` and `sudo` is that:

- `su` requires you to know the password of that alternate user, where
- `sudo` will prompt for the password of the user running the `sudo` command and requires setup so that the user is allowed to run the requested commands/programs.

(When **`root`** runs either `su` or `sudo` no password is required.)

---

Like any init script, the `/etc/rc.local` script is executed by the **`root`** user and you do not need to prepend either `su` or `sudo` to the commands/programs that need to run as root.

You may still need to use `su` or `sudo` in your init scripts if those commands need to be executed **not as `root`** but another user/service-account...

`su -`**`oracle`**`/do/something/as/oracle/user`

Comment: What do I do if  I put su - user /path/to/script.sh in rc.local, and when sourcing it it prompts me for the user password (and closes the terminal afterwards). How do I make it not ask me for the user's password?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, all the scripts and programs are directly called by root.

The `/etc/rc.local` file is called directly by the init process.

Comment: So then, we didn't need to add `sudo` before commands in `/etc/rc.local`?